# Deducing the template type of a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

I have got this snippet which compiles fine with both clang++ and g++, and it seems ok to me:

```
template <typename T, std::vector<T> & v>
struct A{};

int main () {

  static std::vector<int> v;
  A<typename decltype(v)::value_type, v> a;

  return 0;
}
```

...however `A<typename decltype(v)::value_type, v> a;` looks redundant.

I have been trying to modify the template declaration of `A` so that `decltype(v)::value_type` is automatically deduced, but so far without success. It is possible to achieve `A<v> a;` inside `main()`?

Comment: There ain't no such thing as argument deduction for class templates. It only exists for function templates.

Comment: unrelated, why are you taking the non-type parameter as a reference type?

Comment: Use `template <auto &v>`, then check if `v` is a vector with SFINAE or a `static_assert`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It probably won't help here, but we do have [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `template <auto& v> struct A{};` doesn't appear to compile. What kind of C++ feature is this supposed to be? Or did you mean something else, and I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @cigien because non-type template parameters can only be of few types and `std::vector<T>` is not one of them. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think it's a C++17 feature, seems to work [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ksUHHQ).

Comment: @DarioP Thanks, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, you might have:

```
template <auto&> struct A;

template <typename T, std::vector<T> & v>
struct A<v>
{
  // ...
};

int main()
{
    static std::vector<int> v;
    [[maybe_unused]] A<v> a;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41a766e3ffa83423)

In previous standard, you require

```
template <typename T, T& v> struct A;
template <typename T, std::vector<T>& v>
struct A<std::vector<T>, v>{};
```

or similar.

MACRO might help do avoid verbose `decltype(v), v` usage:

```
#define AUTO(v) decltype(v), v
int main()
{
    static std::vector<int> v;
    A<AUTO(v)> a;
    static_cast<void>(a); // Avoid warning about unused variable
}
```